# SQL Server : xp_cmdshell have very limited privilegies

Tags: sql-server, permissions, xp-cmdshell

I don't know if it should be like this. When I'm trying to do anything with `xp_cmdshell` procedure it almost every time gives me `Access Denied`.

For example I can't create new `.txt` file, can't create new user, nothing. I'm logged in with windows administrator user.

Is there any way to run this procedure with administrator privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP_CmdShell will execute under the context of the Service Account running the SQL Server Service. The service account needs the permissions to the external resources.

Could I point out however, that enabling xp_cmdshell is not a good idea. It opens lots of security holes. For example, if your app has an unknown volnerability to SQL injection, a hacker could do all sorts on your network that you rather avoid.

If you must use external resources then better approaches would include a CLR procedure or calling a Job that executes a CMDEXEC step.

Answer (score 0):

`xp_cmdshell` executed by a windows login is executing under an impersonation context. as such any access of a remote resource (eg. access a file on a share, an operation on AD like adding an user) will fall under the constrained delegation restrictions, likely resulting in a access denied because constrained delegation is probably not to be configured on all those resources.